# Rails 3.0.3 - Oracle_enhanced doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have been using Ruby 1.8 + Rails 2.3.5 with oracle_enhanced and it works fine.

Now I recently installed Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3 on another folder, and I can't get it to work.

When I create a simple application and access it, the page returns the following error:

> Please install the oracle_enhanced
>   adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter`
>   (no such file to load --
>   active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter)

I tried to investigate the problem and found the folder Ruby is using, which is C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activerecord-3.0.3\lib\active_record\connection_adapters. In that folder there is no oracle_enhanced_adapter.br file.

The file is in another folder, C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.3.1\lib\active_record\connection_adapters. I tried to copy all rb files from this folder to the other one, I still got an error but it changed:

> Please install the oracle_enhanced
>   adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter`
>   (ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced
>   adapter could not load ruby-oci8
>   library. Please install ruby-oci8
>   gem.)

I noticed that my old Ruby install (1.8) has the same file/folder structure, and oracle_enhanced works.

If I test the connection manually on IRB it works fine, the problem is only with Rails.

Does anyone have a clue?

I'm using Webrick for now, and my gem list is as follows:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.3.1)
activeresource (3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.3)
arel (2.0.6)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hoe (2.8.0)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.13)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
oracle_enhanced (1.2.5)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.3)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
ruby-oci8 (2.0.4 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 3 you have to specify all your gem dependencies in Gemfile. See example of Gemfile with ruby-oci8 and oracle_enhanced adapter: https://github.com/rsim/rails3_oracle_sample/blob/master/Gemfile

After specifying your gem dependencies in Gemfile you need to run `bundle install` to ensure that all necessary gems are installed. After that you should be able to use oracle_enhanced adapter.