# ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter can't load ruby-oci8 library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oci8

After successfully installing the ruby-0ci8 gem and the oracle_enhanced adapter gem I get the following error when I try to fire up my rails project server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:7: 
ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter could not load ruby-oci8 library. 
Please install ruby-oci8 gem. (LoadError)
```

Both the enhanded adapter and ruby-oci8 gem show up in my gem list. Both are present in my Gemfile. Why can't the adapter find the oci8 library?

Some specs on setup I'm running:

- Mac Snow Leopard (10.6.8)
- Ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.8.0]
- Rails 3.0.3
- ruby-oci8 (2.0.4) [gem]
- activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.3.2) [gem]

I've looked at this post: [Rails 3.0.3 - Oracle_enhanced doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561979/rails-3-0-3-oracle-enhanced-doesnt-work). But it's not helping. Anyone else run into this?

==============================

### Answer

I got it figured out. In the end i had an incorrect file structure in /usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2/ where I had stored the files for my oracle instant client. That is what was causing all the issues. Basically I had nested a second instantclient_10_2 directory inside the first and I had my .bash_profile looking in the first directory and not the one below it.

Answer (score 11):

Run `sudo apt-get install libaio1`

Comment: This fixed it for me on centos. Thanks.

Comment: OP has a mac so this probably won't help him.

Comment: This fixed for me in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: This is the correct answer which solve my problem. It should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

-Basically, I added the following 2 lines to the Gemfile:

1. gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.0.6'
2. gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter',  '~>1.4.0'

-then ran the following on command line:

> bundle install

-make sure you don't have other versions of ruby-oci8 or activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter in the Gemfile

---

-For the regular oracle active record adapter I added these lines instead:

1. gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 1.0.4'
2. gem 'activerecord-oracle-adapter', '~>1.0.0.9250'

-then ran the following on command line:

> bundle install

I got the solution from:
[Rails 3.0.3 - Oracle_enhanced doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561979/rails-3-0-3-oracle-enhanced-doesnt-work)

Comment: specifying the exact version of ruby-oci8 in the Gemfile solved my case

Answer (score 0):

This issue is noted on the gems list of [platform specific issues](http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/PlatformSpecificIssue.html). Your most likely solution is to follow the guide provided on how to set up the [Oracle Instant Client](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/06/how-to-setup-ruby-and-oracle-instant-client-on-snow-leopard/).

Comment: I have already followed the guide you mention here. It got me through some of the problems I had getting the oci8 gem to install in the first place. Now that it seems to have been installed correctly I can't understand why it wouldn't be detected by the enhanced adapter.